# Find quarters contained between two dates with Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I've got two separate columns containing two dates that can be either close or far, in a span of a single year. I'm trying to find the quarters that are in between those dates. The first idea that I had was to use MAX and MIN, but it's not working as it should

[image]

The output would be whether it contains each quarter between those dates

Comment: Is your photo supposed to show the output? Doesn't seem to tie with your dates if so

Comment: yes, my mistake, second line should be "0 0 s s"

Comment: For example your first row, the startdate doesn't appear to be the start of the quarter, yet you want it to show as being s?